# How to update Images from list of image urls when Next button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple html page with 4 images displayed at a time and a next button.

Basically I have list of image urls. At the start, the first 4 images from the lists will be shown in the page. Then, when next button is clicked, the next 4 will be chosen and replace the first 4 images displayed. When it reach the end of the list, it will then go back to the first image on the list. Thank you.

Im not that good in html.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will also be of use to you: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ .

Answer (score 0):

It's a basic JavaScript manipulation and can be achieved by simply changing the `src` of 4 images that you're showing with the new one.

Assuming you have a structure somewhat similar to:

```html
<div class="images-container">
    <img id="image1" src="image1.png" />
    <img id="image2" src="image2.png" />
    <img id="image3" src="image3.png" />
    <img id="image4" src="image4.png" />
</div>

<button id="btn">Next</btn>

<script type="text/javascript">
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let new_images = load_next_images() // Your function to get next images
})
</script>
```

Now, once you get the next images, all you have to do is swap the image URLs in the images and you're done! Your modified script would look something similar to:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")
let image1 = document.getElementById("image1")
let image2 = document.getElementById("image2")
let image3 = document.getElementById("image3")
let image4 = document.getElementById("image4")

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let new_images = load_next_images() // Your function to get next images
    image1.setAttribute('src', new_images[0]) // assuming it's a URL
    image2.setAttribute('src', new_images[1])
    image3.setAttribute('src', new_images[2])
    image4.setAttribute('src', new_images[3])
})
</script>
```

That's it!

Disclaimer: The code above is just for demonstration of concept and should be modified as needed, it's neither optimised and nor the recommended way.